# How do I run code at client start (Not at page open) in Blazor

Tags: global-variables, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to run some code to get a user's username and department when they first connect to my Blazor Server Side application. I could just do this using `OnInitialized()` but that appears to only work on the one page in which it was placed. Users will likely be sent separate links to different pages though and I don't want to have to place this code on every page. I discovered that I can place code in my main layout and it will run no matter what page I start on but it runs on every page change and it doesn't allow me to run things asynchronously so that's not ideal. I'm looking for something like a Global.asax but in Blazor if that makes sense.

Edit: Turns out I can run things asynchronously in my layout! I just needed to create a code block like any other razor page. Makes sense. Though It's still weird that we have to put this type of code in the layout. It just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

1. Create a state object (class) that can be injected where needed. This is somewhat like session, but can also have global events. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly).
2. Add it to IoC in Startup.cs. Background info [here](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/build-a-blazor-server-azure-ad-secured-lob-app/)

   `services.AddScoped<MyState>();`
3. Initialize it in MainLayout.razor or elsewhere:

> ```
> if (MyState.User == null)
> {
>     MyState.User = authService.User;
> }
> ```

4. Instantiate in pages/components as needed:

> ```
> [Inject]
> public MyState myState { get; set; }
> ...
> myObj.CreatedBy = myState.User.UserName;
> ```

Comment: Yeah that's basically how I originally did it too. It just feels weird to put code like this in the layout ya know?